# Showing lines that don't have pattern

Tags: awk, xrandr

I am trying to get the monitor name of my secondary monitors using xrandr -q. I am able to get the primary using `xrandr -q | awk '/primary/{print $1}'`, but I also want to get the secondary monitors. I have tried `xrandr -q | awk '/ connected/{print $1}'`, but that also includes the primary. Is there a way that I can do a combo of these two commands (but the first in reverse), where it will show all with "connected" and exclude the one with "primary".

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include the output of xrandr -q.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in awk you can combine conditions using logical operators `&&` `||` `!`

Ex.

```
xrandr | awk '/ connected/ && !/primary/'
```